# Visual Studio C# displays wrong image

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a problem, whenever I try to run any VS Code App my pictures are totally broken. This is what the application looks like without running:

[image: My VS Code screenshot]

After running this happens:

[image: Broken images]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the forms `BackgroundImageLayout` to Stretch using the Properties window. Read more on [Control.BackgroundImageLayout Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimagelayout?view=windowsdesktop-5.0)

[image]

or You can do it using code,

add this into your form constructor

```
public Form1()
{
    this.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: Works fine, ty.